# Import specific objects from one schema to another in Oracle

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, export, data-dump

I've done export of my db and then I've performed import of same in another schema. But, due to some reasons, I've missed out around 1000 objects including tables, procedures in my dump and so, in new schema, those 1000 objects are not available.

Is there any way to import specifically those 1000 object instead of doing export and import again.

Assumption: Both export and import schema exists on same database.

Comment: which tool are you using to export?

Comment: I am using command line (expdp) for export purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restart the export  with the following parameter

```
INCLUDE=TABLE:"IN ('TABL1', 'TAB2')"   --> LIST OF ALL TABLES REQUIRED
or use 
INCLUDE=TABLE --> Will take all tables
INCLUDE=PROCEDURE
INCLUDE=PACKAGE

FOR INDEX : 
INCLUDE=INDEX 
or
INCLUDE=INDEX:"LIKE 'EMP%'"
```

While import what I'd suggest is run with this parameter

```
TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=SKIP
```

if tables already existing it would skip it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Developer "Database Copy..." tool, select source and destination connections and the objects to be copied over.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, you can skip export. Because you missed to take an export of those tables. Only question is whether you have to take full export or only the missed tables. I would recommend to take only the missed tables (use INCLUDE option) and import the same. Nothing will happen to the existing tables.

Check this discussion [What happens to existing tables during import using impdp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748267/what-happens-to-existing-tables-during-import-using-impdp/38749295#38749295)