# What happens to existing tables during import using impdp

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, datapump, impdp, expdp

I want to export and import an entire schema from Prod to Dev, but Dev has already existing tables (that are not there in Prod) which I don't want to be affected.

So, the question is during import (impdp) what happens to those existing tables?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**if you have backuped** full database including create database and create tables queries in backup then there occurs error.

To solve the problem you needs to remove each line that is intented to create database and new table.

**if you have dumped data only** data is added to existing table with no errors. (if contains no syntax error)

**if You don't need data in dev database** Then login to database server and delete all tables that are in prod and then import your database file.

**if You don't want to delete data in dev database** Then create entirely different database import file to that database and modify your connection string.

Comment: I am doing an export and import of only a schema. My doubt is what happens to the existing tables in dev (which are not in prod) during import?